# How to store my app each interaction in database in IOS?

Tags: ios

I want to push my app each activity into server.

- If any button is pressed, it should be save as user pressed that
  button.
- If any alert came also, it should save the activity.
- When any error came inside the app, we should be able to save.

This question is raised because, if user struck on any activity I want to track how the user is using the app step by step.

Can any one please help me to reach the need.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like Flurry? They are now owned by Yahoo but you can probably find some competitors that provide what you need. Or, use Yahoo's stuff.

Comment: Its not about the flurry like thing. Inside the app we need to store the every actions as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some open source library. [XCGLogger](https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger) is your friend.

> Allows you to log details to the console (and optionally a file), just like you would have with NSLog or println, but with additional information, such as the date, function name, filename and line number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) it is free and easy to implement.

**Here is iOS document:** [Document & Guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/)